# Dygraph Y-axis label unit

Tags: dygraphs

Is it possible to add Units to Y-axis values that are showing in legends?.
currently I can able to display graph, but need to modify the legends.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [`valueFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueFormatter):

```js
new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
    "X,Y\n" +
    "1,0\n" +
    "2,2\n" +
    "3,8\n",
    {
      legend: 'always',
      axes: {
        y: {
          valueFormatter: function(v) {
            return v + ' mph';  // controls formatting in the legend/mouseover
          },
          axisLabelFormatter: function(v) {
            return v + ' mph';  // controls formatting of the y-axis labels
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, What if different columns having different units, how can i handle that, in legends?

Comment: Check out the documentation on `valueFormatter`. One of the parameters is the series name.